# iPhone development: local Username and Password Check

Tags: ios, objective-c, class

Sorry in advance if this is a long read, but it's hard to explain:

So, basically i have an application that I want to have 5 users on the app. Each user will have a username, password, and first name. I want to have a way that they can all have a class with their mutator functions and getter functions. So basically my problem is this. I dont know the best way to do that. I have tried creating 5 different classes, each holding a username, and a password and first name(in the code for testing purposes). So i have these classes:

```
user01
user02
...
user05
```

each contain this:

.h file

```
NSString *username;
NSString *password;
NSString *firstName;
-(void)setFirstName: (NSString *)string;
```

.m file

```
username = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello"]; //this actually has a different name in each class
//likewise for password and firstName
```

So on to the question. I know how to access these, but how when the user enteres in their username and password, how do i check to see if it is correct? How do i know if it is user01 loging in or user02?

if you need anymore information from me, feel free to ask, i can't seem to wrap my head around this concept. Thank you

Comment: Use external database or [NSUser Default] to save your userNAme and password

Comment: im not concerned with saving the data right now. I just want to be able to test the username and password against a user input  the easiest way possible (locally).

Comment: use [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:....];

Comment: well my question really isn't where to set the usernames and passwords, it is If i have 5 usernames, how do i tell that the username entered is one of any of those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're having trouble with OOP concepts. You wouldn't create 5 different classes for 5 different users; instead, you would create 5 different instances of a single custom class (e.g., a Person class, or a User class).

```
 User *user1 = [[User alloc] init];
 user1.username = @"Bilbo";

 User *user2 = [[User alloc] init];
 user2.username = @"Frodo";

 // etc.

 // somewhere else in your code…

 if ([user1.username isEqualToString:self.textField1.text])
 {
     // the correct user name was entered for user1
 }
```

Comment: facepalm* you're totally right. Im an idiot. haha, sorry for my inexperience. haha. Thank you a bunch.

Comment: so when a user entered in a username and password, how would i know which instance to test? or would i have to just test them all?

Answer (score 1):

Then you need to create objects for each of these classes and store it in an array. Each time, a user logged in , you can check the values inside this array.

**NOTE**

My suggestion is to use an **NSUserDefaults** or **NSCoder** to store the values. So that, you  dont want to create class for each user. Just create an array with dictionaries and store this array in  **NSUserDefaults** or **NSCoder**.

Comment: Would that still work if i wanted to include a photo for each user?

Comment: yeah definitely. you can add last name also :)

Comment: haha, baby steps man, last names are way down the road. hahahahaha

Comment: so i would create an array in NSUserDefaults that would store the username? and the authentication request would check with that first?

Comment: yeah. in that array you can store user name,password,etc together in dictionary. then you can check in this array